# Call async function from Isolate function

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I am trying to call an async function from the Isolate function.

```
class IsolateExample {

  final ReceivePort port = new ReceivePort();

  IsolateExample(){
     Isolate.spawn(isolateFunction, port.sendPort);
  }

  static isolateFunction(SendPort port){
    print('inside isolateFunction');
    asyncFunction();
  }

  static void asyncFunction() async {
    print('inside asyncFunction');
  }
}
```

**Usage of above class:**

```
final IsolateExample _isolate = new IsolateExample();
```

Above code looks simple but asyncFunction never gets called. I do not have any clue why this is failing.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html ?

Comment: I have simplified the above. In the actual code, I need to return multiple values over the time. I guess compute() does not support multiple returns.

Comment: No, compute only supports a single sync return value. There is an open issue to support a single async return value.

Comment: Well, as of now, that sample has no issue. I'm able to see that `print('inside asyncFunction')`

Answer (score 0):

Isolate will only run your compute once. If you'd like to call the function inside the isolate in intervals, you can utilize [Timer.periodic()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) similar to how it's demonstrated on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63433061).

Once you're done running the function inside the isolate, you can terminate it with `isolate.kill()` - given that `isolate` contains `Isolate.spawn()`