# Dart / Flutter: async behaviour of an Isolate's top level function

Tags: dart, flutter, async-await, future, dart-isolates

Aye Aye good people,
I'm experiencing a weird behavior

when using the top level function of an isolate asynchronously;

you can find example code [HERE](https://github.com/iapicca/isolates_logging), but in short

as **top level function of an isolate** this works:

```
String _syncHandle(int data) {
  return 'done';
}
```

and this doesn't:

```
Future<String> _syncHandle(int data) async {
  return 'done';
}
```

can anybody explain me why?

(or if should work, why isn't doing so in my code?)

thank you in advance

Francesco

...

[edit: just noticed that a similar question has been asked,

nevertheless it is still unanswered
[Call async function from Isolate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334869/call-async-function-from-isolate-function]),

plus issue open on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30683) ]

Comment: Hi sir, I have same problem as you. Have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to update this :/
if you look at the code linked in the question

> isolates_logging/lib/provider/test_isolate.dart

```
  Future<void> _handle(int _m) async {
    final response = ReceivePort();
    isolateTest = await Isolate.spawn(_isolate, response.sendPort);
    final sendPort = await response.first as SendPort;
    final answer = ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send([_m, answer.sendPort]);
    await answer.first.then((p) { 
      _outbound.sink.add(p);});
  }

  static void _isolate(SendPort _initialReplyTo) {
    final port =  ReceivePort();
    _initialReplyTo.send(port.sendPort);
    port.listen((message) {
      final data = message[0] as int;
      final send = message[1] as SendPort;
      send.send(_syncHandle(data));
    });
  }
}

Future<String> _syncHandle(int data) async {
  return 'done';
}
```

note the   send.send(_syncHandle(data)); part

if you do so, you can send only primitives and not futures,
basically that's it

Comment: Don't we need to create functions that we pass into the isolates as top level functions ?? Can we declare them inside, let's say a class ? I tried your code and It seems as everything is working even If I put it inside a class. What's the difference?

Comment: maybe was true 4 years ago, I don't remember